# How to bind multiple params to prepare statement

Tags: php, pdo

I already have working code, however tjis doesn't strip the data and 90% of the data is untrusted. This is written inside an Object which extends the PDO Object.

```
public function query(
    $statement, array $values = array()
) {
    $stmp = parent::Prepare($statement);
    return (empty($values)) ? $stmp->execute() : $stmp->execute($values);
}
```

Is the a way I can use `bindParam()` to do this using a `for` statement?

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't return a boolean. Instead, you should return your statement variable, which you call "$stmp". So just make your code as `return $stmp->execute($values);`

Comment: so my code should look more like: `(empty($values)) ? $stmp->execute() : $stmp->execute($values); return $stmp;` ? I suppose thats better for debugging @YourCommonSense

Comment: it should be just `return $stmp->execute($values);`. I don't understand what debugging you are talking about